# install tinymce plugin

Tags: tinymce, plugin-tinymce

I'm sure this is really simple, but I can't find a quick answer anywhere by searching.  I just want to include the TinyMCE plugin "template" distributed by Moxiecode into my Wordpress editor.  Simply uploading it into the plugins folder isn't sufficient, I get that I need to mess with hooks and filters, but so far I'm unclear what the simplest way to do this is.

Answer (score 2):

There is an existing WordPress plugin that does this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-templates/

Comment: it loads up a bunch of features I don't want, and I actually want to hack the plugin a bit, which I feel would be easier working from the base TinyMCE plugin rather than trying to work with this WP plugin.

Comment: Since the 'base TinyMCE plugin' is not a plugin, but a part of WordPress Core, I strongly suggest you leave it alone and use hooks to modify it externally instead.  Simply put, if it's not in `/wp-content`, DO NOT TOUCH IT.  If the suggested plugin has too many features, go into that plugin's code and see what parts do what you want.  Duplicate them, and go from there.

Comment: SickHippie you're not understanding me, and it's part of why I can't find decent results -- because both Wordpress and TinyMCE use the term "plugin" to describe code snippets that extend the core functionality.  There's a plugin FOR TinyMCE called "Template" that I was trying to install.  I'm not talking about modifying the core.  I'm talking about modifying the "Template" plugin for TinyMCE because it does nearly everything I want, and it's easier to tweak that than to write a new TinyMCE plugin from scratch.  Anyways I figured out how to do what I wanted, so forget it.

Comment: He's saying to use the plugin I linked to above, and modify it to your desire. He's saying NOT to add a plugin to TinyMCE itself - make sure whatever you modify is in wp-content. That said, what did you do to create your desired result?